# Laravel / Eloquent - Column name as variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Eloquent offers a handy way of passing stuff to the database

```
$table_name = new TableName;
$table_name->column_name = "some data";
$table_name->save();
```

I've got quite a lot of data from a form that needs to be validated, so I was wondering if it was possible to replace the column name with a variable, so I can put it in some loop, and get the names and data from arrays.

```
$table_name->$columns[$i] = $data[$i];
```

(though I suppose not written in that way)

**Update**

In the end I've gone with the following:

```
$table_name = new TableName;
$nameArray=[
  1 => 'form-name-1',
  ...
];
$columnArray=[
  1 => 'column_name_1',
  ...
];

for($i=1;$i<=count($nameArray);$i++){
  if(logic logic logic) $table_name->{$columnArray[$i]} = $_POST[$nameArray[$i]];
  else $table_name->{$columnArray[$i]} = NULL;
}
$table_name->save();
```

Comment: If it's validation you need done then check [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) which may save you lots of `if`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do one these:

1) Create with values

```
   $table_name = new TableName([
       "column_name" => "column_value"
   ]);
```

2) Fill

```
$table_name = new TableName();
$table_name->fill([
    "column_name" => "column_value"
]);
```

3) The way you suggested originally:

```
$valuesMap = [
    "column_name" => "column_value"
];
$table_name = new TableName();
foreach ($valuesMap as $column => $value) {
       $table_name->{$column} = $value; //The {} are optional in this case
}
```

Note that to do 1 or 2 all fields you put in the array must be fillable and not guarded.

Comment: Thx! I've gone for a variation of the 3rd option, since I needed to add some more logic before setting the value (the logic was always the same, that's why i asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like an associative array:

```
$table_name['column_name'] 
$column_name = 'column_name';
$table_name[$column_name];
```

Or you can loop their attributes

```
    foreach($table_name->getAttributes() as $value => $key){
     echo "The attr ".$key." has this value: ".$value;
    }
```